# How to fill a combobox when a row in a dbgrid is selected?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-2007, dbgrid

In Delphi 2007 I have a DBGrid. I need to fill a ComboBox when a row in the DBGrid is selected. The data in the the ComboBox depends on the selected row, and can be different for each selected row.

The DBGrid contains products orders. When an order is selected, I need a ComboBox to be filled with batch numbers of the product in the order. This batch number is saved in the order record, when the order is executed.

I could not find a onSelect or onChange event, which I could use to do this.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Is this a lookup table? Is the content coming from another table? Because that's a common scenario provided for by the data aware controls.

Comment: Yes, the content is coming from another table. But using a LookupComboBox (lookup the batchnumbers using the product_id) results in a combobox where all items (batchnumbers) are selected, because they have the same product id. And I need one batchnumber selected, which id is stored in the order-record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use TDataSet.AfterScroll event

Comment: +1 for TDataSet. In these scenario's you are almost always better of using and responding to the underlying datasource and dataset than wrestling with the GUI controls.

Comment: Hi, the TDataSet.AfterScroll does the trick. However, this gives 2 problems. First, the dataset is defined in a datamodule. So to get to the combobox from there is quite odd. Second, the dataset is also used on other locations, for which I don't need this behavior.

Comment: If you use TDBComboBox, you could place its corresponding DataSet (or ClientDataSet) in DataModule too, and refresh it in Grid's DataSet.OnAfterScroll event.

Comment: In that case, I would define a notifier object in your data module, and subscribe to it from your gui.  The notifier object will allow anybody (or nobody) to get notified.

Answer (score 1):

If the data comes from a DataSet in a DataModule, as it looks from comments to @Roman [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472082/how-to-fill-a-combobox-when-a-row-in-a-dbgrid-is-selected/5472271#5472271), you can rely on TDataSource events.

If your datasource is also located in the datamodule, you can place a new DataSource in the form itself (IMO is where it belongs).

Then, use the [TDataSource.OnDataChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSource.OnDataChange) event, from help:

> Write an **OnDataChange** event handler to take specific actions when a field in the current record has been edited and the application moves to another field, or when the current record in the associated dataset changes. **OnDataChange is especially useful in applications that must synchronize data display in controls that are not data-aware**. This event is typically used to make sure the control reflects the current field values in the dataset, because it is triggered by all changes.

The Field parameter is `nil` when the linked dataset is moving to a new record or refreshing a record buffer.  The Field is not nil when the changes belong to a particular field (a user or the program itself changing it's value).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the double click event (OnDblClick) to catch when the user clicks with his mouse and OnKeyPress for the Enter key (Key=#13)

Comment: -1 Doing this by mouse and keyboard event will rapidly become a nightmare and, I bet, 99% of the times will have _some times_ when the ComboBox is not updated properly.